# Curious how to retrieve original vector $x$ from an $x^Tx$ operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, signal-processing

I am doing some analysis on a signal $x(t)$ which is a vector of length $m$. After performing the operation $x^Tx$ of the vector on itself, I get a matrix $Y$ of size $m\times m$. Now, how can I retrieve the original $x(t)$?

Should this be the elements in the diagonal of $Y$? I did some basic plotting and while the diagonal looks similar to original signal vector, they are not equal. Looks straightforward but I am missing something, probably need to normalize it somehow.

In summary,

1. Is it always possible to retrieve the original signal without information loss?
2. If it is possible, how is it done?

Comment: I think you're describing an exterior product $xx^T.$ The formula $x^Tx$ is a dot product

Comment: @HoldenRohrer: nothing prevents OP to begin with a row vector.

Comment: True, I am actually describing an exterior product, and yes, I assumed $x$ to be a row vector.

Comment: What do you know about $x$? Or $\dot x$? Do you have any information on the dynamics of $x$?

Comment: What is the domain of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal holds the *squares* of the original vector.  With it, and the signs of the other entries, you can find $x$ or $-x$ but can't decide between the two.

Comment: In essence, the squaring means I can't retrieve my original signal if there are negative values - that information is permanently lost.

Answer (score 1):

*(I used your notation but you should be aware that the standard is to consider vectors as columns)*

If you take a row-vector $z$ and you do $Yz^T$,
you'll get
$$
Yz=(x^Tx)z^T=x^T(xz^T)=(xz^T)\,x^T.
$$
So as long as the result is nonzero, you are getting a scalar multiple of the original vector. If you use each of the element $e_k$ of the canonical basis, you have that the $k^{\rm th}$ column of $Y$ is
$$
Ye_k=(xe_k^T)\,x^T=x_k\,x^T.
$$
In other words, the columns of $Y$ are multiples of $x^T$, with the coefficients being precisely the entries of $x$. So, if $Y_{kk}=x_k^2\ne0$, you recover $x^T$ up to sign as
$$
x^T=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{Y_{kk}}}\,Y_k,
$$
where $Y_k=Ye_k$ is the $k^{\rm th}$ column of $Y$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the detailed breakdown. Would write the code and see what I get. Safe to say there'll be information loss related to the sign of the retrieved signal.

Comment: That's unavoidable. It's no different than from knowing that $x^2=9$ you cannot know whether $x$ was $3$ or $-3$.